# Почему метод DataLoader.load загружается только один раз?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

```
var DataLoader = {
    xhr: new XMLHttpRequest,
    load: function(url, callback, method) {
        this.xhr.onload = callback;
        this.xhr.open(method || 'GET', url);
        this.xhr.send();
    }
};

function show_data(evt) {
    var xhr = evt.target;
    document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + xhr.response + '</pre>';
};

DataLoader.load('https://api.github.com/users/o0', show_data);
DataLoader.load('https://api.github.com/users/zeckson', show_data);
```

Я вижу только один ответ в теле документа

Код: https://codepen.io/goodnesman/pen/OjLQdJ

Comment: Ты понимаешь Русский?

Comment: Конечно понимаю)

Answer (score 0):

В javascript нет метода `setImeout`. Зато есть `setTimeout`.

```js
var DataLoader = {
    xhr: new XMLHttpRequest,
       load: function(url, callback, method) {
           this.xhr.onload = callback;
           this.xhr.open(method || 'GET', url);
           this.xhr.send();
       }
   };

   function show_data(evt) {
    var xhr = evt.target;
       document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + xhr.response + '</pre>';
   };

   DataLoader.load('https://api.github.com/users/o0', show_data);
   setTimeout(function() {
        DataLoader.load('https://api.github.com/users/zeckson', show_data);
      }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

В примере используется один и тот же объект xhr у которого не может быть 2 коллбека. Правильный вариант:

```
function DataLoader(url, callback, method) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

        xhr.onload = callback;
        xhr.open(method || 'GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    }
```